# How can I replace the ArrayList in my code with an Array and still have it work?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, text-files

I have a computer program in which I have to read code from two text files and then use a merge sort to merge and then sort the two text files. I cannot just put the two inventories back to back into an array and sort! My code works for ArrayLists and so I have commented them out and replaced them with an Array and other Array elements where necessary, all of the changes were made to the Inventory class. There are no syntax errors when I compile however my try catch finds an error.

Here are the two text files:
Store1.txt

```
STORE 1 INVENTORY
ID  QTY U/P       
362 5   12.98
471 2   6.70
792 13  25.00
901 7   2.98
```

and Store2.txt

```
STORE 2 INVENTORY
ID  QTY U/P
163 4   7.20
209 5   11.98
471 5   6.70
608 4   5.90
627 2   9.99
792 1   25.00
812 4   6.00
```

I have multiple classes. This is the tester class where i compile my program from

```
import java.io.*;

public class MergeInventories
{
    public static void main()
    {
        header();
        try
        {
            Inventory store1 = new Inventory(new File("F:\\M359 AP Computer          Science\\JAVA\\Merge Inventories\\Store1.txt"));
            Inventory store2 = new Inventory(new File("F:\\M359 AP Computer Science\\JAVA\\Merge Inventories\\Store2.txt"));

            CombinedInventory mergedInventory = mergeInventories(store1,store2);

            store1.print();
            store2.print();
            mergedInventory.print();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("Error.");
        }

    }

    private static CombinedInventory mergeInventories(Inventory a, Inventory b)
    {

        CombinedInventory inv = new CombinedInventory();

        int i=0,j=0,k=0;

        while(i<a.size()&&j<b.size())
        {
            if(a.getProduct(i).getID() == b.getProduct(j).getID())
            {
                inv.add(new     Product(a.getProduct(i).getID(),a.getProduct(i).getQty()+b.getProduct(j).getQty(),a.getProduct(i).getUP()));
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(a.getProduct(i).getID() > b.getProduct(j).getID())
            {
                inv.add(b.getProduct(j));
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                inv.add(a.getProduct(i));
                i++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        if(j<b.size())
        {
            for(j=j;j<b.size();j++)
            {
                inv.add(b.getProduct(j));
            }
        }
        else if(i<a.size())
        {
            for(i=i;i<a.size();i++)
            {
                inv.add(a.getProduct(i));
            }
        }
        return inv;
    }

    private static void header()
    {
        System.out.println("My Name \n8th Hour \nM359 AP Comp Sci \n");
    }
}
```

The inventory class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Inventory
{
    protected int increment = -1;
    protected int size = 0;
    protected Product[] inventory = new Product[20];
    //protected ArrayList<Product> inventory = new ArrayList<Product>();
    protected String header;
    protected static String CATEGORIES = "ID\tQTY\tU\\P";

    public Inventory()
    {
        header = "TOTAL INVENTORY";
    }

    public Inventory(File file)throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        header = fileScan.nextLine();
        String throwaway = fileScan.nextLine();
        while(fileScan.hasNextLine())
        {
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(fileScan.nextLine());
            Product p = new Product(lineScan.nextInt(), lineScan.nextInt(), lineScan.nextDouble());
            add(p);
        }
    }

    public void add(Product p)
    {
        inventory[increment++]=p;
        //inventory.add(p);
        size++;
    }

    public Product getProduct(int i)
    {
        //return inventory.get(i);
        return inventory[i];    
    }

    public int size()
    {
        //return inventory.size();
        return size;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(header);
        System.out.println(CATEGORIES);
        for(Product p: inventory)
        {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This class Combines the Inventories

```
import java.text.*;

public class CombinedInventory extends Inventory
{
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(header);
        System.out.println(CATEGORIES + "\tVALUE");

        double total = 0;

        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        f.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        for(Product p: inventory)
        {
            System.out.println(p.toString() + "\t" + f.format(p.getQty() * p.getUP()));
            total += p.getQty() * p.getUP();
        }

        System.out.println("Total Value of Stock:\t$" + total);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And finally we have a basic superclass

```
import java.text.*;

public class Product
{
    private int idNum;
    private int quantity;
    private double unitPrice;

    public Product()
    {
        idNum = 0;
        quantity = 0;
        unitPrice = 0;
    }

    public Product(int id, int q, double price)
    {
        idNum = id;
        quantity = q;
        unitPrice = price;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return idNum;
    }

    public int getQty()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getUP()
    {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        f.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        f.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

        return idNum + "\t" + quantity + "\t" + f.format(unitPrice);
    }
}
```

This is what I expect to be printed

```
My Name 
8th Hour 
M359 AP Comp Sci 

STORE 1 INVENTORY
ID      QTY     U\P
362     5       12.98
471     2       6.70
792     13      25.00
901     7       2.98

STORE 2 INVENTORY
ID      QTY     U\P
163     4       7.20
209     5       11.98
471     5       6.70
608     4       5.90
627     2       9.99
792     1       25.00
812     4       6.00

TOTAL INVENTORY
ID      QTY     U\P VALUE
163     4       7.20    28.80
209     5       11.98   59.90
362     5       12.98   64.90
471     7       6.70    46.90
608     4       5.90    23.60
627     2       9.99    19.98
792     14      25.00   350.00
812     4       6.00    24.00
901     7       2.98    20.86
Total Value of Stock:   $638.94
```

However instead of printing all the values "Error" is printed out. I don't understand why this is happening. How can I get it to work using Arrays instead of the ArrayList?

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace() instead of System.out.print("Error."). It will tell you the specific exception and the line it occurs on.

Comment: Why do you want to replace with arrays to start with if `ArrayList` works for you?

Comment: Why do you want to use an array instead of ArrayList? Do you know how many Products you'll have in advance? You *could* put the two inventories into a Collection, implement Comparator and Comparable, and then pass them to Collections.sort. They don't need to be in an array to be sorted.

Comment: The projects requirements state that I must use ArrayLists

Comment: at Inventory.<init>(Inventory.java:27)
 at MergeInventories.main(MergeInventories.java:10)
are the two errors i get when i input e.printStackTrace() instead of System.out.print("Error.").

Comment: "The projects requirements state that I must use ArrayLists" <-- well, you have code which works with ArrayLists, so _why_ do you want to replace with arrays?

Comment: Sorry wow, my brain must be really addled if I cant even think straight after staring at this code. I meant cannot. I am not allowed to use ArrayLists because that would just be, "too easy" according to my teacher.

Comment: @user3421974 It's telling you there's a problem in the constructor of Inventory at line 27 of that file. You'll need an editor that shows line numbers. The stack trace should tell you exactly which line is causing problems.

Comment: is there possibly another way to approach this problem, considering the fact that i must show knowledge of the merge sort as well as use an array.

Comment: there is an error on the line which holds inventory[increment++]=p; this is in the Inventory class. apparently I cant increment the index of the array and assign values to it? This is strange. Java allows direct assignment of array values. And the error on the line which creates the variable which calls my text file also makes no sense. This second error is  located in the MergeInventories class in the main method.

Comment: your `increment` starts at `-1`. That is not a legal array index (the lowest would be `0`). The most immediate fix would probably be to use `++increment` instead of `increment++` or start at 0

Answer (score 0):

If it works with an ArrayList you don't have to do an array. If you really want arrays, you can do theArrayList.toArray();

With an ArrayList it is more simply and a bit more object-oriented.

Comment: OP knows it works with ArrayList, he is asking for the problem which is facing when replaces lists.